# Non-adobe Photoshop templates location

Tags: adobe-photoshop, template, file-management

Where do I put non-adobe photoshop templates so they can be used in the "New File" dialog?

For example, the Apple iOS Photoshop template, which can be found through a simple Google search (the TOS forbid a direct link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop's "New File" dialog and it's **presets** are merely a collections of ***settings***, not templates. The New File presets are essentially a list of numbers for various document options, that's all.

Store templates wherever you want on the hard drive. They aren't part of any UI menu in Photoshop as far as I'm aware.

Comment: So, if I want to use the apple template in Photoshop, I simply open the template file?

Comment: Yes. You simply open the .psd file.. or load the other items via the appropriate panels.